# Understanding __init__ in Python

Tags: python, oop

I am working on a Python file I received and I see a Class with many kinds of variables when it comes to initialization in Python. It is not clear to me what logic I should follow when I define attributes and which ones to initialize or not, below part of the code:

```
class Simulator(object):
    colors = {'gray'    : (155, 155, 155)}

    def __init__(self, env, size=None, update_delay=2.0, display=True):
        self.env = env
        self.size = size if size is not None else self.env.grid_size[0]
        self.road_width = 44
        self.bg_color = self.colors['gray']

        self.quit = False
        self.start_time = None
        self.current_time = 0.0
        if self.display:
            try:
                self.pygame = importlib.import_module('pygame')
                self.pygame.init()
                self.screen = self.pygame.display.set_mode(self.size)
```

For example:

- `env` : it is declared in the parentheses and later on initialized --> Clear
- `size`: it is declared but when initialized it uses `self.env.grid_size[0]`. How `env` can have an attribute `grid_size` that it was not defined or initialized?
- `road_with`: Why it is not mentioned in the parentheses? I would have just put `road_with` in the parentheses with the default value 44
- `bg_color`: Why it is not defined in the parentheses?
- Why `quit`, `start_time`, `current_time` are not defined in the parentheses?
- How it works to declare but not initialize a `self.pygame` which is related to a module which is not previously called in the code?
- How it works to init another module with the `self.pygame.init()`?

Comment: Have you worked with any language besides python?

Answer (score 5):

> size: it is declared but when initialized it uses self.env.grid_size[0]. How env can have an attribute grid_size that it was not defined or initialized?

In the line before, `self.env` is set as the first positional argument the user supplies to the initializer when creating an instance of `Simulator`. It is up to the user to supply an object which has an attribute `grid_size`. (This should probably be mentioned by a doc-string or a type hint.)

> road_with: Why it is not mentioned in the parentheses? I would have just put road_with in the parentheses with the default value 44

Only let the user know what he must know about the inner workings of an object. It's the principle of information hiding. If every instance of our object should carry the attribute `road_width` with the value `44`, why bother the user with another optional argument where it's not clear what calling the initializer with other values for `road_width` would even do?

> bg_color: Why it is not defined in the parentheses?
>   Why quit, start_time, current_time are not defined in the parentheses?

see above

I don't understand your last two questions.

Answer (score 4):

The main question here seems to be: Why are some attributes that are initialized in `__init__` not also parameters to `__init__`? The answer is: Because you don't want the user to be able to set those.

For example, those could represent some internal state of the object. Think of an `Iterator` class. The parameter could be a list, but its internal state is also defined by the current index in that list. That index could be initialized in `__init__` to `0`, and it does not make sense to pass it as a parameter. This seems to apply to your `quit`, `start_time` and `current_time` attributes`.

Or maybe some attributes are derived from others, e.g. you could have a `Rectangle` class, with parameters `width` and `height`, and another attribute `area`, which is derived from those two parameters. This seems to be the case e.g. for the `self.screen` attribute.

And some attributes may just be constant and unchangeable, as seems the case with `road_width` and `color`. Those could maybe be moved outside of the instance, if they are the same for each instance of the class anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So basically the parameters in the parentheses are the ones that you want to allow the user to modify while all others you initialize but you dont include in the parentheses, is that the logic?

Comment: @Mariano Yes, that's it. Parameters that have a default value _can_ be supplied, those without one _have to be_ supplied, and attributes that don't have a corresponding parameter can _not_ be user-supplied.

Comment: @Mariano Consider creating a character on a videogame. You can change the initial appearance, the name, the race, the class, but there are things that you (as a user) can't change, such as your initial level, your initial money, etc.